# Does the chanting in Azdaha's phase 2 boss theme have any meaning?

Tags: genshin-impact

There is somewhat Mandarin Chinese-sounding chanting that occurs in the background of Azdaha when he enrages and is in either Phase 2 - 4.

Is this all gibberish or does the chanting actually have any meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The translate was base on my understanding， so it could be wrong.
The chanting is about Azhdaha's past(definitely.）

随君兮 巍宇如山巅兮
夫终途 君长归兮陌路

随重岩争雄
恨繁囿兮作土

君 叹石而捻土为目
为万人 为忠骨
山崩岩阻  坚如磐石

地龙起 轰轰如交击兮
忠勇义 平涛青天
诉汝声 誓宁愿跟随兮山雄呼

There are all the chanting in Chinese. It could have some error.

First, let me explain some word in the chanting that will make you understand it better. It is only the meanings that used in the chanting, it could have other meanings if you use it otherwise, but this is not Chinese StackExchange.
随-follow
君-It stand as Emperor, which is Morax(you know who, but prevent spoiler to others)
兮-No meaning itself, Just a added word to make the line sound better, it sometimes act as a word to smooth the sentence, sometimes express the feeling of sigh.
如-as(Ex： 强如狮- strong as a lion.）
夫-It stands as Azhdaha here
陌路-It stands as "different path" here.
恨-Hate，hatred.
山-mountain                                                                           忠-Loyal to Emperor
地龙-Earth Dragon, which is Azhdaha.

Now let me translate it line by line. The words inside the brackets are not in the chanting, but just put it there for understanding.   And inside 【】is my explanation.

随君兮 巍宇如山巅兮-（Azhdaha）Follow Morax, （Azhdaha is）As tall as a mountain.)
夫终途 君长归兮陌路- At the end of my journey【Which is before the Azhdaha has been strain by Morax.】，Morax（and Azhdaha）  walk on a different path now【which means “you and me turn against each other now”】.

随重岩争雄- follow the Morax in the Archon War to fight.【well，重岩 doesn‘t mean Morax，it means more like the Liyue before the victory in Archon War. Or to Rephrase the setence， Fight on Morax’s side】
恨繁囿兮作土-The hatred grow like a luxuriant garden and stack up.【which describe when Azhdaha was retrain by Morax，his hatred grows. By the way，this line is also the quest name for “ No Restoring This Past Land of Beauty” in Chinese，but I don‘t think this sentence tranlate out as that，it doesn‘t make sense when connect with other line.】

君 叹石而捻土为目- Morax give eyes to Azhdaha.
为万人 为忠骨- （Azhdaha）Protects People，and is a loyal bone.
山崩岩阻  坚如磐石- Moutain collapse and the stone hinders. Solid As Rock.【The First section of this line is not a good translation but this is the best I could do. This first part is just saying that Azhdaha can do great destruction.】

地龙起 轰轰如交击兮- when Azhdaha move，it shakes and sound like weapons strikes together.【The second part of this line is not that good. But this line just mean that Azhdaha can shake the earth and make loud noise.】
忠勇义 平涛青天- Loyal，Brave. Can stop the wave and bring the blue sky.【 Actually there is three word descibe in the first section of this line，but two of them are both loyal，one is loyal to Emperor，the other is loyal to friend.】
诉汝声 誓宁愿跟随兮山雄呼- Say your word. I will Yell with the mouatin.【the moutain stands for Azhdaha here.】